# Goldtouch USB Keyboard reverses keystrokes in fast typing -- expected?

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, thinkpad

I am running into an odd keyboard problem: some key combinations end up reversed (e.g. "pl" ends up being emitted as "lp") when I'm typing quickly. The problematic ones are the key combos I hit with two adjacent fingers on my right hand-- in other words, the combos I can hit the fastest.  No idea how fast is "fastest", but I guess around 50-150 msecs gap between them.

I'm trying to track down whether this represents a failed keyboard, an inherent limitation of my [Goldtouch USB keyboards](http://www.goldtouch.com/p-64-goldtouch-adjustable-keyboard-black.aspx), or a software problem on my Windows 7 Lenovo T500.

I use a PS/2 version of the same Goldtouch keyboard at home with no problems.  I've tried another USB keyboard with my laptop and can't repro the problem. I've also used this keyboard on other laptops without a problem.

According to [this SU thread](https://superuser.com/questions/16893/do-usb-or-ps-2-keyboards-respond-faster), USB keyboards have higher latency than PS/2 keyboards-- up to 30 msecs. I find it hard to imagine that I can type key combos faster than 50 msecs, probably more like 100-150.

Anyone encountered this problem with this or another keyboard? If so, how did you fix it?  Any idea if there's a "keyboard log" or some way to diagnose the problem inside Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt Windows would have such a feature, i'm getting a feeling you have an inferior keyboard, or poorly constructed version of a good keyboard.

My keyboard is wireless and you would make the assumption that it wouldn't keep up, but it does. I recommend just getting a new keyboard for peace of mind, they aren't too expensive?

At any rate you should try a few keyboards on the computer to determine the source of the problem :)

Comment: It's a hardware problem. Just about any modern keyboard should be able to handle a 'fast' typist's typing speed. If you're running into problems with reversed keys it's probably time to get a new keyboard.