# USB-to-PS/2 adapter

Tags: usb, keyboard, performance, mouse, adapter

I have a follow up questions from a Q&A I was reading-up, *[PS/2 vs. USB keyboards: performance and energy consumption](https://superuser.com/q/472233)*.

1. I have a USB-to-PS/2 adapter. I can attach it to a USB port on my computer and it gives me two PS/2 ports, for a keyboard & a mouse. If I use this adapter, would my processor be polling the devices or rather getting interrupts from the peripheral devices?
2. I don't have a problem with using USB 3.0 or PS/2. I am under an impression that USB 3.0 is supposed to fix this polling behavior. Is it true? If it is, then does it mean that a USB 3.0 mouse and keyboard would be at-least as fast as PS/2, if not more?
3. My motherboard has a green and purple combo port. So, if I get a PS/2 splitter instead a USB-to-PS/2 adapter, would it be faster?

*<sub>(This question was moved from: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9328/9394)</sub>*

Comment: @user902300 Please don't post video URLs in comments without context. Answers are for answers; comments are for clarifying the question or suggesting improvements. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

1. yes polling will ocure even with adapter
2. nope, usb 3.x doesnt fix polling anyhow
3. wouldnt say "faster", but without polling

Comment: Can you explain these? Or provide references to support what you're saying? Thanks!